# Problem while trying object recognition

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!
I want to try the object recognition kitchen on my ubuntu 12.04 and ros hydro. I followed the install tuto (http://wg-perception.github.io/object_recognition_core/install.html#install ), so I've done this for install:

```
$ cd catkin_ws/
$ mkdir ork/src
$ sudo apt-get install libopenni-dev ros-hydro-catkin ros-hydro-ecto* ros-hydro-opencv-candidate ros-hydro-moveit-msgs
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.sh
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_core
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/capture
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/reconstruction
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/linemod
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/ork_renderer
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/tabletop
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/tod
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/transparent_objects
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_msgs
$ git clone http://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_ros
$ cd ../ && catkin_make
```

after I try this:

```
$ rosrun object_recognition_core push.sh
$ source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.sh
$ roscore
```

in a new terminal:

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

in a new terminal:

```
$ rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane
```

AND HERE I HAVE AN ERROR!!!:

```
simonus@robert:~$ rosrun object_recognition_capture orb_template -o my_textured_plane
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simonus/catkin_ws/ork/src/capture/apps/orb_template", line 12, in <module>
    from object_recognition_capture.ecto_cells.capture import PlaneFilter, FeatureFinder
ImportError: No module named object_recognition_capture.ecto_cells.capture
simonus@robert:~$
```

And my paths are:

```
$ export | grep ROS
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="hydro"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/home/simonus/catkin_ws:/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros"
```

I don't know what I do wrong!Please I need help :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159266/problem-while-trying-object-recognition/) by [happylulu](https://answers.ros.org/users/15351/happylulu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-08**:
Can you import `object_recognition_capture` as a whole?

**Comment by [stefie10](https://answers.ros.org/users/18161/stefie10/) on 2014-05-19**:
I had the same error; I had to set my python path to the ork build directory: export PYTHONPATH=SOMETHING/ork/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same error; I had to set my python path to the ork build directory: export PYTHONPATH=SOMETHING/ork/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

---

Originally posted by [stefie10](https://answers.ros.org/users/18161/stefie10/) with karma: 16 on 2014-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0